# Why the fields of a typescript class that are updated inside a setInterval are undefined in other methods of the class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, web

I start an interval within the start method and within the interval the class fields are being updated, but when I want to use the class fields in another method (for example: stop method) they are undefined.

```
export class Timer {

    currentCycleStartTime: number;
    threadTimer: NodeJS.Timer;
    timmerRunning: boolean;
    elapsedTime: number;
    remainingTime: string;
    lastRemainingTime: string;

    readonly SECONDS_IN_CYCLE = 1000;

    constructor() { }

    start(callback: { (time: string): void}): void {
        const STEP: number = 10;

        this.timmerRunning = true;
        this.currentCycleStartTime = Date.now();

        this.threadTimer = setInterval(() => {
            if (this.timmerRunning) {
                this.elapsedTime = Date.now() - this.currentCycleStartTime

                if (this.timeIsOver())
                    this.stop()

                callback(this.getTime())
                console.log('start', this.currentCycleStartTime) // here it is ok
            }
        }, STEP)
    }

    timeIsOver(): boolean {
        return this.elapsedTime >= this.SECONDS_IN_CYCLE;
    }

    getTime(): string {
        const remainingTime: Date = new Date(this.SECONDS_IN_CYCLE - this.elapsedTime);
        return this.fixTime(remainingTime.getMinutes()) + ':' + this.fixTime(remainingTime.getSeconds());
    }

    fixTime(time: number): string {
        return time < 10 ? '0' + time : '' + time;
    }

    stop(): void {
        this.timmerRunning = false;
        clearInterval(this.threadTimer); // this is undefined
         console.log('start', this.currentCycleStartTime) // it is undefined
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this kind of problem, just use global.setInterval instead of setInterval.
Please take a look :

```js
export class Timer {

  currentCycleStartTime: number;
  threadTimer: NodeJS.Timer;
  timmerRunning: boolean;
  elapsedTime: number;
  remainingTime: string;
  lastRemainingTime: string;

  readonly SECONDS_IN_CYCLE = 1000;

  constructor() { }

  start(callback: { (time: string): void }): void {
    const STEP: number = 10;

    this.timmerRunning = true;
    this.currentCycleStartTime = Date.now();

    this.threadTimer = global.setInterval(() => {
      if (this.timmerRunning) {
        this.elapsedTime = Date.now() - this.currentCycleStartTime

        if (this.timeIsOver())
          this.stop()

        callback(this.getTime())
        console.log('start', this.currentCycleStartTime) // here it is ok
      }
    }, STEP)
  }

  timeIsOver(): boolean {
    return this.elapsedTime >= this.SECONDS_IN_CYCLE;
  }

  getTime(): string {
    const remainingTime: Date = new Date(this.SECONDS_IN_CYCLE - this.elapsedTime);
    return this.fixTime(remainingTime.getMinutes()) + ':' + this.fixTime(remainingTime.getSeconds());
  }

  fixTime(time: number): string {
    return time < 10 ? '0' + time : '' + time;
  }

  stop(): void {
    this.timmerRunning = false;
    clearInterval(this.threadTimer); // this is Timer.threadTimer: NodeJS.Timer
    console.log('start', this.currentCycleStartTime) // it is Timer.currentCycleStartTime: number
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried to use global but throwsme error "global is undefined" 

Comment: have you installed @types/node ?

Comment: try (global as NodeJS.Global).setInterval

Comment: try window.setInterval ... if you are in browser environment